# Why can't we assign a single character to a string but can assign multiple characters?

Tags: c#, string, character, assign

```
static void removeSpaces(ref String arg)
{
    String temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < arg.Length; ++i) {
        if (arg[i] != ' ')
        {
            temp = arg[i];   // gives error
            temp += arg[i];  // works fine, no error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `arg[i]` is `char`, `temp` is `string`. There is no implicit conversation from `char` to `string`. If you _carefully_ read your error message, you could find it. For your second line, `+` operator calls `ToString` method for `arg[i]`, that's why it becames `temp = temp + arg[i].ToString()` which is valid.

Comment: because we cant assign a single character to string!! you have to do this `arg[i].ToString();`

Comment: Why not just `str = str.Replace(" ", string.Empty);` ?

Comment: Are you trying to get everything after the last space? `temp = arg.Split(' ').Last();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Line, you are trying to assign a char,

```
temp = arg[i];
```

Here you are appending a char to a string which will work,

```
temp += arg[i];
```

To make it work , you need to convert to string

```
 temp = arg[i].ToString();
```